# How to efficiently define daily constant?

Tags: python, database, performance, postgresql, flask

Using the (awesome) Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/), I'm building a website, for which I have 3 "constants" which change every morning (so my constants are not very constant, I know, but still). I need these constants in pretty much every call to the webserver (both page and API requests) so I want the retrieval of these constants to be very efficient.

I guess the most efficient way to define these constants is to manually set them in the code every morning. But since I'm lazy, and the idea behind programming is to automate things, I see no reason to handle this differently. That's why I thought of 3 different ways;

1. Store the constants in a DB (I'm using Postgres for my website)
2. Store the constants in a little file which I load in.
3. Store the constants in a more speed optimised key value store, such as [Redis](http://redis.io/)

but:

1. Storing them in my postgres DB is of course easy, but creating a full seperate table for 3 single records which I'm going to overwrite every day doesn't really seem logical.
2. Opening a file for every request also takes time, although benchmarking would obviously tell the answer.
3. Setting up a full redis server (which I've never done before, but seems like a cool challenge) also seems a bit overkill for the simple things I want to store.

I have the idea that I'm overlooking a very simple cool trick, that I just can't think of. Could anybody enlighten me as to what would be the smartest thing to do? All tips and ideas are welcome!

Comment: Could not these constants be computable, so as not to have to store them?
I mean could you use a combination of the year/month/day?

Comment: Can you give us example of "constants" values ?

Comment: @Simpom - Unfortunately not. I get them from an external source using an API call.

Comment: @Dragu - The constants are simple Floats: 123.456 for example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables too.

When you retrieve your "constants" you set it in environment:

```
import os
os.environ['MY_DAILY_CONST_1'] = 'dailyconst1'
os.environ['MY_DAILY_CONST_2'] = 'dailyconst2'
...
```

And when you have to access it:

```
import os
myconst1 = os.environ['MY_DAILY_CONST_1']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Flask, you can also save the constants as global variables at the application level.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('my_app')

constant1, constant2, constant3 = retrieve_constants()

app.jinja_env.globals['constant1'] = constant1
app.jinja_env.globals['constant2'] = constant2
app.jinja_env.globals['constant3'] = constant3
```